# POM references a dependency and a parent the same way. How we choose what is what?

Tags: maven, pom.xml

I found that syntax of `parent` and `dependency` references in POM are practically the same:

```
<parent>
    <groupId>com.topdesk</groupId>
    <artifactId>tis-parent</artifactId>
    <version>3.4</version>
</parent>
```

`Dependency` has the same inner content. Why we choose to put something as `parent` instead of using `dependency`?

Comment: some more detailed docs about the subject: https://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Inheritance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These are different concepts. Referencing a parent makes Maven look for a *pom* from which it inherits (using all the plugin definitions, profiles, declared dependencyManagement etc.), i.e. the parent and your pom are put together as one and executed.

Using a *dependency* means that Maven looks for a *jar* (unless you explicitly tell it to look for a pom, which essentially means that it adds all dependencies from that pom as transitive dependencies). This jar is put on the classpath (together with its dependency tree).